# JVM native thread loops and uses 100% CPU

Tags: java, jvm, playframework-2.0, java-8, infinite-loop

I have a Play Framework 2.4 application which runs on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, Java 8u40. After some time, my application stops responding. When I check CPU load using `top`, I see that java process is using 100% CPU. When I run `jstack -F -m <PID>` I see looping thread is among JVM native frames.

Here is the jstack output of the looping thread:

```
----------------- 1062 -----------------
0x00007f01a8a531cc  _ZNK5Klass12next_siblingEv + 0xc
0x00007f01a86b18ee  _ZN15ciInstanceKlass24has_finalizable_subclassEv + 0xbe
0x00007f01a85f683e  _ZN12GraphBuilder23call_register_finalizerEv + 0x9e
0x00007f01a85fd2a5  _ZN12GraphBuilder13method_returnEP11Instruction + 0x295
0x00007f01a860385f  _ZN12GraphBuilder27iterate_bytecodes_for_blockEi + 0x6cf
0x00007f01a8600c4b  _ZN12GraphBuilder18iterate_all_blocksEb + 0x14b
0x00007f01a86015e6  _ZN12GraphBuilder15try_inline_fullEP8ciMethodbN9Bytecodes4CodeEP11Instruction + 0x996
0x00007f01a86017df  _ZN12GraphBuilder10try_inlineEP8ciMethodbN9Bytecodes4CodeEP11Instruction + 0x11f
0x00007f01a8602912  _ZN12GraphBuilder6invokeEN9Bytecodes4CodeE + 0xbb2
0x00007f01a860383d  _ZN12GraphBuilder27iterate_bytecodes_for_blockEi + 0x6ad
0x00007f01a8600c4b  _ZN12GraphBuilder18iterate_all_blocksEb + 0x14b
0x00007f01a86015e6  _ZN12GraphBuilder15try_inline_fullEP8ciMethodbN9Bytecodes4CodeEP11Instruction + 0x996
0x00007f01a86017df  _ZN12GraphBuilder10try_inlineEP8ciMethodbN9Bytecodes4CodeEP11Instruction + 0x11f
0x00007f01a8602912  _ZN12GraphBuilder6invokeEN9Bytecodes4CodeE + 0xbb2
0x00007f01a860383d  _ZN12GraphBuilder27iterate_bytecodes_for_blockEi + 0x6ad
0x00007f01a8600bf2  _ZN12GraphBuilder18iterate_all_blocksEb + 0xf2
0x00007f01a86057a7  _ZN12GraphBuilderC1EP11CompilationP7IRScope + 0x527
0x00007f01a860e127  _ZN7IRScopeC1EP11CompilationPS_iP8ciMethodib + 0x1e7
0x00007f01a860e23f  _ZN2IRC1EP11CompilationP8ciMethodi + 0x9f
0x00007f01a85ed25b  _ZN11Compilation9build_hirEv + 0xdb
0x00007f01a85ed61e  _ZN11Compilation19compile_java_methodEv + 0x6e
0x00007f01a85ed74e  _ZN11Compilation14compile_methodEv + 0x4e
0x00007f01a85edabe  _ZN11CompilationC1EP16AbstractCompilerP5ciEnvP8ciMethodiP10BufferBlob + 0x25e
0x00007f01a85ee869  _ZN8Compiler14compile_methodEP5ciEnvP8ciMethodi + 0xa9
0x00007f01a874143a  _ZN13CompileBroker25invoke_compiler_on_methodEP11CompileTask + 0xc9a
0x00007f01a87423e6  _ZN13CompileBroker20compiler_thread_loopEv + 0x5d6
0x00007f01a8cf596f  _ZN10JavaThread17thread_main_innerEv + 0xdf
0x00007f01a8cf5a9c  _ZN10JavaThread3runEv + 0x11c
0x00007f01a8ba9ee8  _ZL10java_startP6Thread + 0x108
```

This problem started after I upgraded from Play 2.3 to 2.4 and Java 7 to Java 8. I don't think Play upgrade has anything to do with this. It looks like it is related to JIT compilation.

What is this thread for and what could be the cause of infinite loop and of course how can I fix/workaround this?

Thanks.

Comment: this is not offtopic

Comment: 8u40 is not the current version, try updating and see if it changes things

Comment: @the8472 I've updated to 8u66 and it didn't help.

Comment: That was a JVM bug seems to be fixed now https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8085965 https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/jvm_hang_with_cms_collector

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue before and for me it was code cache being full, try inspecting the code cache usage via jconsole

[image]

and try increasing it

```
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
```

choose the value based on your app's usage